# How i can put other img to JSP file to table

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee

Okay, at first excuse me for my English skill.
I have a problem. Servlet load to jsp ArrayList with file address and directory address. I need to for director was one image and for files other image. Now it's look's like this [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BY7yp.jpg)

p.s. If you can help me with drop down list (when click on directory open and change image from close folder to open folder) I'll be very happy.

yours respectfully

JSP file:

```
<table border = "1">
    <c:forEach items = "${fath}" var = "fath">
    <th> <a href="/back?name=${fath}">
        <img src="opfolder.png"> </a>
    </th>
    <th>
        ${fath}
    </th>
    </c:forEach>
    <c:forEach items= "${FileZ}" var="FileZ">
        <tr>
            <td>
            <a href = "open?name=${FileZ.father}">
            <img src ="clfolder.png"/>
            </a>
            </td>
            <td>${FileZ.name}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>`
```

Java Servlet file :

```
@WebServlet(name = "ToOut" , urlPatterns = "/fileman")
    public class ToOut extends HttpServlet {
        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
}
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
       request.setAttribute("FileZ",AllFiles.getDir(AllFiles.getAdress()));
        request.getRequestDispatcher("fileman.jsp").forward(request,response);
    }}
```

Comment: Its not clear, what is stored in "fath" attribute by Servlet. Please also write the servlet code that populate "fath" attribute. If possible, please try to make the overall question more clear? Thanks